# Why can't I access my extensions' settings on the frontend?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

Trying to access a few settings that I've created in my `constants.txt` file. It looks like this:

```
plugin.tx_my_ext {
    settings {
        # cat=plugin.tx_my_ext/urgences; type=boolean; label=Activer les urgences
        activerUrgences = 0
    }
}
```

Then in my `setup.txt` file I have this:

```
plugin.tx_my_ext.settings.activerUrgences = {$plugin.tx_my_ext.settings.activerUrgences}
```

Any reason why I wouldn't be able to access my settings using `{settings}` in my Fluid layout?

BTW, my extension name does include an underscore `_` between the words. I have tried removing the underscore, then removing the `tx_`, and then a combination of those two.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. For ext with key `my_ext` it should be `plugin.tx_myext.settings`
2. Make sure that you 'Included static from extension' in your TypoScript Template. If your ext is not available on the list add it in `ext_localconf.php` like that:

   ```
   \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile($_EXTKEY, 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'MyExt');
   ```
3. Do not forget to clear *System cache* and *FE cache* at least million times ;)
4. Use TypoScript object browser to check if on given page your plugins TS is still available (maybe something resets TS in meanwhile:

[image]

5. Finally make sure that you don't clear `$this->settings` array within your controller, if you do manipulate it for any reason assign it to the view again before view rendering,like that:

   ```
   $this->view->assign('settings', $this->settings);
   ```

Comment: Actually, line #2 was in my  `ext_tables.php` file. Should I also add it to my `ext_localconf.php`? But you should know that my extension was already in the 'Included static from extension' in my Typoscript template.

Comment: No, it;s only in `ext_tables.php` so there's probably cache issue ' empty the content of `typo3temp` folder (just delete all files in it, but don't delete folder itself) and check if it helps

Comment: no dice. in my `setup.txt` file i have this line `plugin.tx_udmnouvelles.settings.activerUrgences = 1` but on the front on my default template, when I try to access {settings} using `f:debug, I get an empty array

Comment: I don't have any controllers (that I know if), so I don't believe I can reset my settings. Also my settings are in the Object Browser

Comment: Also, newb question here, but how would I reassign the settings to the view again?

Comment: Check my last edit (point no.5) if it won't help that means that I can't help you anymore without access to the working instance.